# Is it undesirable to defensively apply std::move to trivially-copyable types?

Tags: c++

Imagine we have a trivially-copyable type:

```
struct Trivial
{
    float A{};
    int B{};
}
```

which gets constructed and stored in an `std::vector`:

```
class ClientCode
{
    std::vector<Trivial> storage{};
    ...

    void some_function()
    {
        ...
        Trivial t{};
        fill_trivial_from_some_api(t, other_args);

        storage.push_back(std::move(t));  // Redundant std::move.
        ...
    }
}
```

Normally, this is a pointless operation, as the object will be copied anyway.

However, an advantage of keeping the `std::move` call is that if the `Trivial` type would be changed to no longer be trivially-copyable, the client code will not  silently perform an extra copy operation, but a more appropriate move. (The situation is quite possible in my scenario, where the trivial type is used for managing external resources.)

So my question is whether there any technical downsides to applying the redundant `std::move`?

Comment: Why are you coding for the future instead of what you have now?

Comment: A similar dilemma (albeit not equal) then might be if some_function will be used in multithreaded architecture later on - should you prematurely add a lock_guard for storage?

Comment: I think if you do it, it's not because of defensive. If that value won't be used by caller, `std::move` is to show it explicitly.

Comment: Sure there are technical downsides, mainly more code which means it is harder to read, reason about and compilers and analyzers doing more work. That doesn't answer your actual question though. I'd say in the general case of generic types you would `std::move` and in the special case of trivial types the general case code still works correctly, so you stick to that. But that is an opinion, something that SO doesn't like.

Comment: @Default Valid point.

Comment: @nwp This is pretty much my opinion too. Without thinking too much about what the type really does, I wrote `std::move` because that's what I meant to do with the object. I would very much like to not make my code over-specialize, but sometimes there could be tricky compiler optimization issues.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> However, an advantage of keeping the `std::move` call is that if the `Trivial` type would be changed to no longer be trivially-copyable, the client code will not  silently perform an extra copy operation, but a more appropriate move.

This is correct and something you should think about.

---

> So my question is whether there any technical downsides to applying the redundant `std::move`?

Depends on where the moved object is being consumed. In the case of `push_back`, everything is fine, as `push_back` has both `const T&` and `T&&` overloads that behave intuitively.

Imagine another function that had a `T&&` overload that has completely different behavior from `const T&`: the semantics of your code will change with `std::move`.